Concentration bounds for a mixture of a fixed value and a uniform distribution
Suppose we have a mixed random variable $R= (1-p)X + pU$, where $X$ is just a single value $X \in [-\pi, \pi]$, $0 \leq p \leq 1$, and $U \sim \text{Uniform}[-\pi, \pi]$. I.e. a single trial returns $X$ with probability $p$, otherwise it returns a sample from $U$ with probability $1-p$.
I would like to give (preferably two-tailed) concentration bounds for the number of trials needed to estimate $X$ to additive accuracy $\epsilon$ and confidence $\delta$. The parameter $p$ is known in advance. If we denote trials $R_i$ and use an estimator $\hat{R} = \frac{1}{n(1-p)} \sum_{i=1}^n R_i$, then naive application of Hoeffding gives, I think,
$$
n \geq \frac{2\pi p^2}{\epsilon^2(1-p)^2}\log\frac{1}{\delta},
$$
But can a tighter bound be derived?

I wonder if you mean that $R=(1-\alpha)X+\alpha U$ where $\alpha \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$.

Sure, this makes sense.

Just curious:  Using the mode of a sample if the mode is unique and zero otherwise is a much, much better estimator of $X$.  Is there some reason for the estimator in your question?

You write $\delta$ is the "confidence". Can you clarify a little?

One more comment on the estimator $\hat{R}$:  when $n<20$ and $p>1/2$ there can be a large fraction of the estimates being way outside of $[-\pi, \pi]$.  This is support of my question as to why that estimator.  Is that estimator either being used or proposed to be used for any important decisions?

I'm not wedded to that estimator, and in fact using the mode would also be acceptable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Presuming that "$\delta$ is the confidence", as the OP writes, implies that we want a confidence interval that includes $\delta$ probability mass.
The estimator is
$$\hat X = \frac 1{1-p}\frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^nR_i \implies S_n \equiv \sum_{i=1}^nR_i = n(1-p) \hat X.$$
The range of $R_i$ is
$$R_i \in \left[-\pi,\quad \pi\right].$$
Moreover, $\hat X$ is unbiased and hence so is $S_n$,
$$E(S_n) = n(1-p)X.$$
We examine the probability (since $\epsilon$ is the length and $\delta$ the confidence),
\begin{align}
\delta =\Pr\left(|\hat X - X| \leq \epsilon\right)& =1- \Pr\left(|\hat X - X| \geq \epsilon\right)\\
 &= 1- \Pr\left(|n(1-p)\hat X - n(1-p) X| \geq n(1-p)\epsilon\right)\\
&\implies \Pr\left(|S_n - E(S_n)|\geq n(1-p)\epsilon\right) = 1-\delta
\end{align}
The left hand side is Hoefding's left-hand side, so
$$1-\delta \leq 2\exp\left\{-\frac {2\epsilon^2\cdot n^2\cdot (1-p)^2}{n\cdot 4\pi^2}\right\},$$
which leads to
$$n \leq \frac{2\pi^2}{\epsilon^2 (1-p)^2} \log\frac{2}{1-\delta}.$$
We obtained a "should not be greater than" result, rather than a "must be greater than" one. This is what Hoeffding's inequality can give us in this case.
Set $\epsilon = 0.1$, $\delta = 0.9$ and $p=0.5$ to get
$$ n\leq 23,653.$$
What would happen if we did $25,000$ trials with $\epsilon$ and $p$ as above?
The right-hand side of Hoeffding would become $\approx 0.084$ so we would obtain
$$1-\delta \leq 0.084 \implies \delta \geq 0.916.$$
Namely with this specifics and $25,000$ trials, we would obtain confidence higher than we required.
But the result is silent as regards with how small $n$ we can get away with. Namely, the specific $(\epsilon, \delta)$ pair given $p$, could possibly be reached with much smaller $n$ than $23,653$.

If $\tilde{X}_n$ is the estimator that JimB is talking about then for $\epsilon > 0$
\begin{align}
\delta =\Pr\left(|\tilde{X}_n - X| \geq \epsilon\right)
&= \Pr\left(|\tilde{X}_n - X| \geq \epsilon, \text{at least $n-1$ samps from uniform}\right)\\
&\le \binom{n}{n-1} p^{n-1}(1-p)+  p^n .
\end{align}

Should the probability be exactly $\binom{n}{n-1} p^{n-1}(1-p)+ \binom{n}{n} p^n (1-p)^0=p^{n-1} (n (-p)+n+p)$ rather than $\leq p^{n-1}$?

$\binom{n}{n-1} p^{n-1}(1-p)+  p^n = p^{n-1}(n+p-np) $
